# Python code will only print first line while using input

Tags: python

I am attempting to print the code, but only the first line shows up in the module when ran.

I tried moving lines around entirely but couldn't figure it out. The code is below

```
num1=input("10")
num2=input("50")

try:
  print(int(num1)+int(num2))
except:
  print("one of those is not a number")
```

It will only show 10 on the module.

Comment: How are you running the code?  Are you using Sublime Text?

Comment: Get rid of the `try: except:` for one; you're hiding any and all errors you might be getting.

Comment: Also note that `num1=input("10")` _doesn't_ assign the value `10` to `num1`

Comment: The second print line is intended to catch if either `num1` or `num2` is not an integer so it won't run unless such case happens

Comment: The `input("10")` is what prints the "10" and is then waiting for you to input something.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused on how `input()` works. The string you provide is printed and what you type into the terminal after it is returned to the variable. If you have no way to type to the program, then `input()` is not what you're looking for. For more help, the docs for `input()` can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what kind of problem are you having here, so I will suggest a few solution to the potential problems you are trying to fix.

- **The other lines are not printed :** looks like that you are a little bit confused about the input() method. See this to learn about : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
- **The program does not run :** the program is unindented and it's mandatory to indent the code in Python, so try to give a tab in the try "body" and in the except "body".